# Search Filters Like Ecommerce Sites

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cakephp, search

I'm developing a new site in cakephp 3. I need to implement a Search page like [This Page](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Paint-Ceiling-Paint/N-5yc1vZbbbv). How to implement the Search like this. Is there any Scripts to do this or if anyone have an idea, Please share with me. In this search the page is loaded very quickly and the URL values also Changed. Please help me to implement the search like this.

Answer (score 0):

Like many search tools, most of them are using SQL power. As you may probably know, SQL provide an operator named "LIKE" that allow you to define search pattern :

E.g :

```
 SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%man'
```

Will return products whose names are either Superman, or Batman, or anything ending with "man". You can probably use the same trick to search products with their description or their name for example.

Comment: I have multiple columns in SQL Table. i need to pass the each values in the filter to mysql and if the product goes more than like 5000 it will slow down. Can you see the Attached Link

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to search in cakephp, your can start with  cakeDc search plugin.[here](https://github.com/CakeDC/search). comes with fairly  easy to grasp docs.